# Error with siunitx and sfrac as fraction-command

Tags: siunitx, xfrac

I like to combins `siunitx` with `xfrac` (see example below). This worked really well for years but today (after a fresh update to my TeX Live 2021 installation) it stopped working.

Here's a short example:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  per-mode=fraction,%
  fraction-command=\sfrac%
}
\begin{document}
My unit: \unit{\m\per\s}.
\end{document}
```

This used to work (do not remember exactly when) but now I get an error:

```
./mwe.tex:9: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...sh_box -\box_dp:N \l__xfrac_slash_box -\height 
                                                  
l.9 My unit: \unit{\m\per\s}
                          .
```

If I omit the `\per` or comment out the `fraction-command` line, everything works.
Therefore it seems that the current definition of `\sfrac` is not compatible with how `siunitx` wants to use the command (I assume).

Any ideas on how to get `\sfrac` working nice with `siunitx` again?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: open an issue at the siunitx github.

Comment: Done. Issue at GitHub is: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/558#issue-1046801882